# Scheduling tasks with dynamic arguments to run periodically with celery in django

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have a tasks that contains dynamic arguments I want to run periodically, how do I pass dynamic elements to the tasks arguments when the task is being called in django celery beat?
Here is the task I want to run periodically:

```
@task(bind=True)
def generate_export(export_type, xform, export_id=None, options=None):
    """
    Create appropriate export object given the export type.

    param: export_type
    param: xform
    params: export_id: ID of export object associated with the request
    param: options: additional parameters required for the lookup.
    binary_select_multiples: boolean flag
    end: end offset
    ext: export extension type
    dataview_pk: dataview pk
    group_delimiter: "/" or "."
    query: filter_query for custom queries
    remove_group_name: boolean flag
    split_select_multiples: boolean flag
    index_tag: ('[', ']') or ('_', '_')
    show_choice_labels: boolean flag
    language: language labels as in the XLSForm/XForm
    """
    username = xform.user.username
    id_string = xform.id_string
    end = options.get("end")
    extension = options.get("extension", export_type)
    filter_query = options.get("query")
    remove_group_name = options.get("remove_group_name", False)
    start = options.get("start")

    export_type_func_map = {
        Export.XLS_EXPORT: 'to_xls_export',
        Export.CSV_EXPORT: 'to_flat_csv_export',
        Export.DHIS2CSV_EXPORT: 'to_dhis2csv_export',
        Export.CSV_ZIP_EXPORT: 'to_zipped_csv',
        Export.SAV_ZIP_EXPORT: 'to_zipped_sav',
        Export.GOOGLE_SHEETS_EXPORT: 'to_google_sheets',
    }

    if xform is None:
        xform = XForm.objects.get(
            user__username__iexact=username, id_string__iexact=id_string)

    dataview = None
    if options.get("dataview_pk"):
        dataview = DataView.objects.get(pk=options.get("dataview_pk"))
        records = dataview.query_data(dataview, all_data=True,
                                      filter_query=filter_query)
        total_records = dataview.query_data(dataview,
                                            count=True)[0].get('count')
    else:
        records = query_data(xform, query=filter_query, start=start, end=end)

        if filter_query:
            total_records = query_data(xform, query=filter_query, start=start,
                                       end=end, count=True)[0].get('count')
        else:
            total_records = xform.num_of_submissions

    if isinstance(records, QuerySet):
        records = records.iterator()

    export_builder = ExportBuilder()

    export_builder.TRUNCATE_GROUP_TITLE = True \
        if export_type == Export.SAV_ZIP_EXPORT else remove_group_name
    export_builder.GROUP_DELIMITER = options.get(
        "group_delimiter", DEFAULT_GROUP_DELIMITER
    )
    export_builder.SPLIT_SELECT_MULTIPLES = options.get(
        "split_select_multiples", True
    )
    export_builder.BINARY_SELECT_MULTIPLES = options.get(
        "binary_select_multiples", False
    )
    export_builder.INCLUDE_LABELS = options.get('include_labels', False)
    export_builder.INCLUDE_LABELS_ONLY = options.get(
        'include_labels_only', False
    )
    export_builder.INCLUDE_HXL = options.get('include_hxl', False)

    export_builder.INCLUDE_IMAGES \
        = options.get("include_images", settings.EXPORT_WITH_IMAGE_DEFAULT)

    export_builder.VALUE_SELECT_MULTIPLES = options.get(
        'value_select_multiples', False)

    export_builder.REPEAT_INDEX_TAGS = options.get(
        "repeat_index_tags", DEFAULT_INDEX_TAGS
    )

    export_builder.SHOW_CHOICE_LABELS = options.get('show_choice_labels',
                                                    False)

    export_builder.language = options.get('language')

    # 'win_excel_utf8' is only relevant for CSV exports
    if 'win_excel_utf8' in options and export_type != Export.CSV_EXPORT:
        del options['win_excel_utf8']

    export_builder.set_survey(xform.survey, xform)

    # change the dhis2csv exports to standard csv format
    if extension == 'dhis2csv':
        extension = 'csv'

    temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=("." + extension))

    columns_with_hxl = export_builder.INCLUDE_HXL and get_columns_with_hxl(
        xform.survey_elements)

    # get the export function by export type
    func = getattr(export_builder, export_type_func_map[export_type])
    try:
        func.__call__(
            temp_file.name, records, username, id_string, filter_query,
            start=start, end=end, dataview=dataview, xform=xform,
            options=options, columns_with_hxl=columns_with_hxl,
            total_records=total_records
        )
    except NoRecordsFoundError:
        pass
    except SPSSIOError as e:
        export = get_or_create_export(export_id, xform, export_type, options)
        export.error_message = str(e)
        export.internal_status = Export.FAILED
        export.save()
        report_exception("SAV Export Failure", e, sys.exc_info())
        return export

    # generate filename
    basename = "%s_%s" % (
        id_string, datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f"))

    if remove_group_name:
        # add 'remove group name' flag to filename
        basename = "{}-{}".format(basename, GROUPNAME_REMOVED_FLAG)
    if dataview:
        basename = "{}-{}".format(basename, DATAVIEW_EXPORT)

    filename = basename + "." + extension

    # check filename is unique
    while not Export.is_filename_unique(xform, filename):
        filename = increment_index_in_filename(filename)

    file_path = os.path.join(
        username,
        'exports',
        id_string,
        export_type,
        filename)

    # seek to the beginning as required by storage classes
    temp_file.seek(0)
    export_filename = default_storage.save(file_path,
                                           File(temp_file, file_path))
    temp_file.close()

    dir_name, basename = os.path.split(export_filename)

    # get or create export object
    export = get_or_create_export(export_id, xform, export_type, options)

    export.filedir = dir_name
    export.filename = basename
    export.internal_status = Export.SUCCESSFUL
    # do not persist exports that have a filter
    # Get URL of the exported sheet.
    if export_type == Export.GOOGLE_SHEETS_EXPORT:
        export.export_url = export_builder.url

    # if we should create a new export is true, we should not save it
    if start is None and end is None:
        export.save()
    return export
```

and this is where I call the tasks in the celery beat schedule:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'download_csv': {
   'task': 'onadata.libs.utils.export_tools.generate_export',

    # There are 4 ways we can handle time, read further
   'schedule': crontab(minute='*'),
    # If you're using any arguments
    'args': ()
  }
}
```

how do I pass  parameters into the arguments for the tasks??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass argument dynamically in Celery Beat. I think your function is not suitable with periodic task.

Instead of giving a factor directly to the `generate_export` function, it must be changed to get the required items within the function. Or change to a simple asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. The `args` field in `beat_schedule` is fixed at startup and does not change afterward.

But there is a hackish way to pass different arguments to your task.

Use the `before_task_publish` signal to add custom data in headers.

```
from celery.signals import before_task_publish

@before_task_publish.connect
def before_publish(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    if sender == "tasks.generate_export":
        headers["custom_args"] = {
            "export_type": "some_val"
            "xform": "some_val"
            "export_id": get_export_id()
            "options": options_dict
        }
```

By default, Celery uses JSON [serializer](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#calling-serializers). So, make sure the data you add to headers are JSON serializable. Alternatively, you can use pickle to serialize the data, but it brings [security concerns](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/faq.html#isn-t-using-pickle-a-security-concern) with it.

Now you can access these headers in a [bound task](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/4.4.2/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks).

```
@task(bind=True)
def generate_export(self):
    args = self.request.get("custom_args", None)

    # do something with args
```